# How to store a global variable in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

First of all I want to say that I have a website where I want to change the language without reloading the page. That is why I inserted buttons for EN and DE.

```
<button lang="de" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm language" >DE</button>
<button lang="en" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm language" >EN</button>
```

Furthermore my CSS looks like this:

```
 html.en :lang(de) {
  display: none;
}
html.de :lang(en) {
  display: none;
}
```

And that is my JQuery script:

```
if ($("html").hasClass('de')) {
  $('html').addClass('de');
}
else{
     $('html').addClass('en');  
}

$('.language').click(function(){
($('html').toggleClass('de en'));


    });
```

And finally here is my html tag:

```
<html class="">
```

My Problem is that if I change the language on one page it automatically changes back if I click on a link to a new page. I know there is a problem with my JQuery if function. But I really do not know how to solve this.
Maybe with JQuery cookies?

Comment: cookie or localStorage is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To keep trace of the current locale, the best practice is to set it in the url, this approach allows the user to switch lang when he needs!!

If you're not able to keep the lang on the url you may consider the use of WebStorage...
Try something like this:

```js
var I18nService = (function($, storage) {
  var STORAGE_KEY = 'MY_SITE_CURRENTLOCALE';
  function I18nService() {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      this.setCurrent(this.current);
    });
  }
  
  I18nService.prototype.available = ['en', 'de']
  I18nService.prototype.current = (function() {
    var res = this.available[0];
    var previous = this.getStored();
    
    if(previous) {
      res = previous;
    }
    
    return res;
  })();

  I18nService.prototype.getStored = function() {
    return storage.getItem(STORAGE_KEY);
  };

  I18nService.prototype.store = function() {
    storage.setItem(STORAGE_KEY, this.current);
    return this;
  };

  I18nService.prototype.setCurrent = function(newVal) {
    this.current = newVal;
    return this.store().updateClasses();
  };

  
  I18nService.prototype.getCurrent = function() {
    return this.current;
  };

  I18nService.prototype.updateClasses = function() {
    $('html').removeClass(this.available.join(' ')).addClass(this.current);
    
    return this;
  };
  
  return new I18nService();
})(jQuery, window.localStorage.bind(window) /* or sessionStorage, dependes on what you need */);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I do not know how to integrate it, or do I have to change something ?

Comment: You have to put it in your application, I think there aren't bugs...

When you want to change locale you need to call I18nService.setCurrent('de');

It's a Singletone, auto loaded, class...

I hope this is all you need!!

Comment: let me some stuff about the code, it is working properly?

@Jesse what "double exclamation points?" means ?

Comment: "user to switch lang when he needs!!"

Answer (score 2):

Yes - every page load will result in a new JavaScript scope.  If you need to maintain any state between pages, you'll need to use cookies or keep something appended on to the URL between pages.  (Even if using server-side components, a client-side identifier is typically required to keep a session ID for the server to relate back to.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API may also be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

An easy way you could do this on the client side is by using query strings.  You can append a query string to the end of a url like this:

```
?lang=en
```

Then in your javascript you can parse out the query string and handle accordingly.  While there are good libraries out there for parsing query strings ([like this](https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string)), here is a very simple piece of JS that will grab the query string.  This ONLY works if there is one query string though.  If you plan on using more query string in the future, you will need to implement something better.

```
var language = location.search.replace(/^.*?\=/, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the buttons to prevent reload page since you don't need to reload this page

```
$('.language').click(function(e){
($('html').toggleClass('de en'));
     e.preventDefault();  
    });
```